# How to fix an error with layers in geom_rect?

Tags: r, ggplot2

While creating a ggplot chart using geom_rect, I encountered the following error:

```
Error in `geom_rect()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'Weekly_Sales' not found
```

My code:

```
ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = Date, y = Weekly_Sales)) +
  geom_rect(data = df2, color = 'white',aes(xmin = as.Date(xmin), 
  ymin = ymin, xmax = as.Date(xmax), ymax = ymax, fill = changes),alpha = .4) +
  geom_line(color = 'orange', size = 1.25) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('blue', 'green'))
```

The `Weekly_Sales` column is in the `df1` dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `inherit.aes = F` inside `geom_rect`.

> inherit.aes
> If FALSE, overrides the default aesthetics, rather than combining with them.

```
ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = Date, y = Weekly_Sales)) +
  geom_rect(data = df2, inherit.aes = F, color = 'white',aes(xmin = as.Date(xmin), 
  ymin = ymin, xmax = as.Date(xmax), ymax = ymax, fill = changes),alpha = .4) +
  geom_line(color = 'orange', size = 1.25) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('blue', 'green'))
```